# Can we drop indexes in a materialized view manually before complete refresh (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: oracle11g, refresh, materialized-views

I have a materialized view with 12 million records. Each time a complete refresh is done with atomic_refresh set to false. No logging is enabled in the refresh and the mview is a local copy of a remote table. No joins are present. The mview takes about an hour to refresh and I want to decrease the refresh time.

There are about 20 indexes and I think since it is a complete non atomin refresh, dropping and rebuilding the indexes is taking a long time. Can I drop the index manually before the refresh and build them manually after the refresh is complete ?

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  Do you have some reason to believe that would actually improve performance?  If you're copying 12 million rows over the network each time you do a refresh, I would expect that network throughput would be, by far, the bottleneck.  Do you have some reason to believe that index maintenance is, in fact, the bottleneck?  Can you do an incremental (fast) refresh instead of doing a complete refresh?

Comment: I have other mviews with same amount of data and fewer indexes refreshing within reasonable time. This is why I think index maintainence is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you?  Sure.

Is that the most effective way to tune your process?  Probably not.  Doing an incremental refresh rather than a complete refresh would allow you to move only the data that actually changed over the database link and would probably significantly decrease the cost of the index maintenance.  Plus, if you're doing a non-atomic refresh, that implies that Oracle is doing a direct-path load in the background.  That means that index maintenance is already being deferred until after the data is loaded into the table which limits the potential benefit of dropping and recreating the indexes.

If you decide to manually drop and recreate the indexes every time, you'd have to ensure that this is kept up to date as new indexes are added or removed.  That's a maintenance hassle that is relatively easy to overlook when some developer just wants to add or remove an index.

Comment: I agree that incremental refresh is the efective way. But if I do the incremental refresh, will that create an overhead of logging when changes are made to the master table. And the logging is not actually enabled anywhere in the database.

Comment: @anesh - Yes, you'd need a materialized view log on the source table to track the changes.  That would incur some overhead on `INSERT` operations on the source.  But it would significantly reduce the overhead of reading every block from the source table every time you do a refresh.